# Error initialising model with UUIDField django

Tags: python, django

### Problem :

So, I have been trying to make an object of the model `Trade` with an initial value to the **identifier** from my custom function `gen_rand_string()`.

But the problem is when, I am initialising it.

If I remove the **initializer** and set the `UUIDField` to `NULL`, it works out to be fine.

This is the error, I am getting :

> TypeError at /admin/account/trade/add/
>
> int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Trade'

My **Trade** class :

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    NEW_TRADE = 'N'
    CANCELLED_TRADE = 'C'
    PENDING_TRADE = 'P'
    STATUS_OF_TRADE = (
        (NEW_TRADE, "New"),
        (CANCELLED_TRADE, "Cancelled"),
        (PENDING_TRADE, "Pending")
    )
    TYPE_BUY = 'B'
    TYPE_SELL = 'S'
    TYPE_OF_TRADE = (
        (TYPE_BUY, "Buy"),
        (TYPE_SELL, "Sell")
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField('UserProfile', related_name='trades')
    identifier = models.UUIDField(null=False, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    finished_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10, null=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPE_OF_TRADE, null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_OF_TRADE, default=PENDING_TRADE, null=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.identifier = gen_rand_string()
        super(Trade, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.identifier

    def __str__(self):
        return self.identifier
```

My **gen_rand_string()** :

```
def gen_rand_string(purpose=''):
    if purpose:
        return purpose + '_' + get_random_string(length=64 - len(purpose))
    else:
        return get_random_string(length=64)
```

#### Suggestions :

I am making a random string for each trade in not a better way, would someone suggest somewhat better option, or something they would have it in their place.

**I am using python 2.7 which is the reason of my initialisation of the object in a different way**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are discouraged from overriding `__init__` for Django models. You use your `gen_rand_string` as the field's default:

```
identifier = models.UUIDField(null=False, editable=False, default=gen_rand_string)
```

However you probably don't need to define your own `gen_rand_string` method - just use `uuid.uuid4`, as in docs for [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield).

```
identifier = models.UUIDField(null=False, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Comment: thanks but I'm still getting an error, regarding the UUID field. `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, UUID found`

Comment: Try returning `unicode(self.identifier)` in your `__unicode__` method. Note that if you are using Python 2 then you don't need to define `__str__` and `__unicode__`. Either use `@python_2_unicode_compatible
` and define `__str__`, or just define `__unicode__`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

problem is with your init function syntax.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Trade, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.identifier = gen_rand_string()
```